# What is Teradata's "like any" syntax in oracle?

Tags: sql, oracle, teradata

I am converting Teradata syntax to Oracle. 
I have this

```
SELECT * FROM TABLE_A
WHERE proc_name LIKE any ('%AB%','%AC%')
```

in Teradata but it is not supported in Oracle.

Does anyone know what is the alternative syntax of **Like any** in Oracle?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: And `LIKE ALL` translates to a `AND`ed condition :-)

Answer (score 4):

Use `or`:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE proc_name LIKE '%AB%' or
      proc_name LIKE '%AC%';
```

This is the "normal" way the logic would be expressed in SQL.

Oracle also supports regular expressions, so if you prefer:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE_A
WHERE regexp_like(proc_name, 'AB|AC');
```

The two `like`s probably have better performance.

Comment: Aha! Thanks! When you get used to the way it works in TD then you'll forget the original logic.